# What could make Firefox render an incorrect border width?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a weird problem in a project I'm working on. Firefox (22) magically eats up 1 pixel of my border. All other browsers are fine.

Now, the layout is really complex and I can't show all the code, but I hope this is the relevant part:

HTML

```
<div class="carouselitem unselectable photo selected">
    <img alt="" src="https://example.com/something.jpg" class="carouselimg">
    <div class="typeicon"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.mediacarousel .carouselitem.selected {
    border: 5px solid white;
    height: 71px;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 136px;
}
.mediacarousel .carouselitem:hover .carouselimg,
.mediacarousel .carouselitem.selected .carouselimg {
    left: -5px;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
.mediacarousel .carouselitem,
.mediacarousel .carouselimg {
    width: 146px;
}
.mediacarousel .carouselimg {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.mediacarousel .carouselarrow, .mediacarousel .carouselscroller,
.mediacarousel .carouselitems, .mediacarousel .carouselitem, .mediacarousel .carouselimg {
    height: 81px;
}
img, .unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
.mediacarousel .carouselitem .typeicon {
    display: none;
    filter: inherit;
}
```

Firebug shows this:

[image]

Uhm, 4.8px, seriously? CSS looks good:

[image]

But, 1 complete pixel is somehow disappearing...

[image]

I have never seen something like this, and I had no success in finding the root of the evil. So my question is:
What exactly may be the cause for this? Is it a known bug?

---

*Edit*:
Turns out this only happens when the [font size in Windows 7 is set to 125%](http://answers.microsoft.com/thread/a53032c5-764b-4cd7-8967-9bb87b9bb157). Still not something you would expect. Here's a fiddle where you can try yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/mdynm/1

Comment: @CanGeliş Thanks for the link, but this is a different issue. The `box-sizing` is just fine in my case.

Comment: Yes sorry I just deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest it might have something to do with the default font or zoom set to other than 100%. This is going to be a tricky one to narrow down much farther than that.

Comment: @brentonstrine Right. I guess it's a bug in Firefox and I'll post a bug report shortly.

Comment: @Pumbaa I suggest that you put your edit into an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this only happens when the [font size in Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller) is set to something else than 100%.

Reported as a bug in Firefox:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=890383

Comment: Window 10 also has this bug.