# written Border vs shown Border

Tags: html, css, border

I've got a Problem with simple plain html/css Borders.

If i do something like that:

```
#demoDiv {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This cssText will style the div-element with the ID "demoDiv" to a green box with black border. The Box should be 102 px heigh and 102 px width, right?
But now comes my Problem.... Firefox tells me, that this box is 101,6px heigh and width. 
The only border-width, that is working is "0" - the others had to be multiply by 0.8.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't set the  box-sizing: border-box to your page. By default all Html pages content-box set in the box-sizing which simply means that it calculates the all sizes from the margin box to content area box. Make sure to learn more about it as it will useful for in the future.You learn more about border-box from the Mozilla- Mdn.

Comment: In this Case I want the default box-sizing: content-box. This Excludes Margin, Padding Border and sets height and width only for the Content. Margin and Padding is 0 by css so there is just the border with 1px

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
[What could make Firefox render an incorrect border width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394545/what-could-make-firefox-render-an-incorrect-border-width) 
to sum it up: Firefox renders the border-width on zoom.
Thanks for responding